# FB OG Product Object not displaying all fields

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

This is my first interaction with OG and I'm sure I am missing something simple. I have the following as a self hosted object:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="3...." />
<meta property="og:title" content="..." />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://.com/img/..." />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://.com/myobjectpage.html" />
<meta property="og:type" content="product" />
<meta property="product:product_link" content="https://.com/p/64/..." />
<meta property="og:description" content="This course...." />
```

Now everything is showing properly **EXCEPT** product:product_link it doesn't show anywhere. The debugger gives it a green light so not sure what is wrong.